# How can I verify existence of text inside a table view row given its index in an XCTest UI Test?

Tags: xcode, swift, xctest, xcode-ui-testing

I am using XCTest UI Test framework to check rows in a table view. In my test I need to verify the existence of text in a table view row given its index.

I was thinking of using `tableRows.elementBoundByIndex` method, but it did not return anything. The number of rows returned by calling `tableRows.count` is zero. The table is present and filled because I can query the text inside the rows successfully:

```
XCTAssertEqual(app.tables.staticTexts["Cute Alpaca"].exists)
```

How can I verify existence of a text in a row given its index in an XCTest UI test?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

It turns out that `tableRows` doesn't actually detect rows in the `UITableView`. Use `cells` instead.

I have a feeling that `tableRows` and `tableColumns` are used to do testing on Mac OS X where you have actual tables while on iOS we have `UITableViewCell` and `UICollectionViewCell`. Or this could be a bug as we are still in the beta period.

```
let table = app.tables.element
XCTAssertTrue(table.exists)

let cell = table.cells.elementBoundByIndex(2)
XCTAssertTrue(cell.exists)
let indexedText = cell.staticTexts.element
XCTAssertTrue(indexedText.exists)
```

or the one liner

```
XCTAssertTrue(app.tables.element.cells.elementBoundByIndex(2).exists)
```

Answer (score 1):

For your case, I think this code will help you.

```
let tableCellContainer = app.tables["HomeTableView"].cells.element(boundBy: 1) // Get the first Cell
let cell = tableCellContainer.staticTexts["Brazil"]
XCTAssert(cell.exists)
```

Regards,