# How to get the index of a cell given the text inside in XCUITest?

Tags: swift, xcode, xctest, xcuitest

I'm testing a tableview the cell content in XCUItest. In my case, I don't know the order of the cell text, nor am I allowed to set an accessibility id for the text.  How can I get the index of a cell given the text inside?

[image]

For instance, if I wanted to get the index of the cell containing text "Cell 2 Text" I would try something like this:

```
func testSample() {
    let app = XCUIApplication()
    let table = app.tables
    let cells = table.cells

    let indexOfCell2Text = cells.containing(.staticText, identifier: "Cell 2 Text").element.index(ofAccessibilityElement: "I dunno")
    print(indexOfCell2Text)
}
```

I feel like I'm close, but I'm unsure. Can anyone suggest a solution?

I apologize if this question has been asked before. I wasn't able to find anything specific about this.

References I visited beforehand:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xcuielementquery/1500842-element

[How can I verify existence of text inside a table view row given its index in an XCTest UI Test?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32365327/how-can-i-verify-existence-of-text-inside-a-table-view-row-given-its-index-in-an/32389031)

[iOS UI Testing tap on first index of the table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36566558/ios-ui-testing-tap-on-first-index-of-the-table)

Answer (score 1):

The most reliable way really is to add the index into the accessibility identifier. But, you can't. Can you change the accessibility identifier of the cell instead of the text ?

Anyway, if you don't scroll your table view, you can handle it like that :

```
let idx = 0
for cell in table.cells.allElementsBoundByIndex {
    if cell.staticTexts["Text you are looking for"].exists {
        return idx
    }
    idx = idx + 1
}
```

Otherwise, the index you will use is related to cells which are displayed on the screen. So, after scrolling, the new first visible cell would become the cell at index 0 and would screw up your search.

Comment: I think scrolling the table will not have any effect here. Is that any special case?

Answer (score 0):

```
for index in 0..<table.cells.count {
    if table.cells.element(boundBy: index).staticTexts["Your Text"].exists {
        return index
   }
}
```